# Display: inline-block last-child width 100% doesn't align with its siblings

Tags: html, css, padding, margin

I'm working with CSS `display: inline-block`.

```css
.container div
{
  display: inline-block;
    width: calc((100% - 13px) / 2);
    margin: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #5e5e5e;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
    border-bottom: 2px solid #80D0C7;
    position: relative;
}

.container div:last-child
{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="red">Red</div>
    <div class="green">green</div>
    <div class="blue">blue</div>
    <div class="orange">orange</div>
    <div class="black">black</div>
</div>
```

I put `width: 100%` on div last-child. But it give an extra padding/margin.
My question, how to make the div last-child fit width 100% without any extra padding/margin?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: flex` in `.container`, then `flex-basis: calc(50% - 4px)` (where `4px` is the sum of the margins in each `div`) in all divs and in last one set `flex-basis: 100%`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container div {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #5e5e5e;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 2px 2px 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #80D0C7;
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 calc(50% - 4px)
}

.container div:last-child {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red">Red</div>
  <div class="green">green</div>
  <div class="blue">blue</div>
  <div class="orange">orange</div>
  <div class="black">black</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, it's still show us the extra margin/padding there. Please have a look

Comment: Where? you have to be more specific, maybe a screenshot of the real issue

Comment: Yes, I updated my question. Please have a look

Comment: @HiDayurieDave take a look at the updated answer

Comment: Awesome... Cheers for your answer. (y)